# In WXPython how do I make it so sizer lines will be seen?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a sizer defined as follow:

```
sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
sizer_1.Add(....)
```

How can I make it so the borders of the sizer will be shown in the screen?

So it will look like that:

[image]

Comment: What is the use case?  Just for testing or the end user has to see them?  For the first case you can use the WIT - http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool

Comment: what do you mean use case? the sizer has borders.. I just want this borders to shown on screen

Comment: A sizer is a logic UI element, not a physical one (meant in the way the sizer layouts elements, but is itself not visible). What you presumably want is a ``StaticBox``/``StaticBoxSizer``, see [link](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/StaticBox.html#appearance-control-appearance).